# GCP Dataflow JOB REST response add displayData object with { "key":"datasetName", ...}

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

Why this code of line doesn't generate displayData object with `{ "key":"datasetName", ...}` and how I can generate it if it's not coming by default when using BigQuery source from apache beam?

```
bigqcollection = p | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(project=project,query=get_java_query))
```

[UPDATE] Adding result that I try to produce:

```
"displayData": [
                    {
                        "key": "table",
                        "namespace": "....",
                        "strValue": "..."
                    },          
                    {
                        "key": "datasetName",
                        "strValue": "..."
                    }
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether your problem is that no display data is being generated, or that the generated display data does not include the dataset name specifically?

Comment: no, displayData is generated, problem is with datasetName, I try to integrate some tool and it requires datasetName key to exist within displayData array. Not sure how to create this object with such key datasetName in dataflow job (e.x. if we press to view Equivalent REST response, it doesn't appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading [the implementation of `display_data()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.32.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L605) for a `BigQuerySource` in the most recent version of Beam, it does not extract the table and dataset from the query, which your example uses. And more significantly, it does not create any fields specifically named `datasetName`.

I would recommend writing a subclass of [`_BigQuerySource`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.32.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L508) which adds the fields you need to the display data, while preserving all the other behavior.